# VB.Net: Open CSV File in Datagridview

Tags: vb.net, csv, datagridview, streamreader

I'm having trouble with loading data from a CSV file to Datagridview.
Im getting following error while trying to read the file: 
*"The input array is longer than the number of columns in this table"*

```
Dim SR As StreamReader = New StreamReader(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Programs & "/PURTB/Data/" & TextBox1.Text & ComboBox3.Text & ".csv")
    Dim line As String = SR.ReadLine()
    Dim strArray As String() = line.Split(","c)
    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
    Dim row As DataRow

    For Each s As String In strArray
        dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn())
    Next

    Do
        line = SR.ReadLine
        If Not line = String.Empty Then
            row = dt.NewRow()
            row.ItemArray = line.Split(",")
            dt.Rows.Add(row)
        Else
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
```

The file I'm using looks something like this:
[CSV File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSni6.png)

Update: Maybe the problem comes from the export code.

```
Dim StrExport As String = ""
    For Each C As DataGridViewColumn In DataGridView1.Columns
        StrExport &= """" & C.HeaderText & ""","
    Next
    StrExport = StrExport.Substring(0, StrExport.Length - 1)
    StrExport &= Environment.NewLine

    For Each R As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        For Each C As DataGridViewCell In R.Cells
            If Not C.Value Is Nothing Then
                StrExport &= """" & C.Value.ToString & ""","
            Else
                StrExport &= """" & "" & ""","
            End If
        Next
        StrExport = StrExport.Substring(0, StrExport.Length - 1)
        StrExport &= Environment.NewLine
    Next

    Dim tw As IO.TextWriter = New IO.StreamWriter(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Programs & "/PURTB/Data/" & TextBox1.Text & ComboBox3.Text & ".csv")
    tw.Write(StrExport)
    tw.Close()
```

Comment: That indicates that one of the lines in the file has more field values that the first row that you used to create a columns in the table.  You need to look closely at your data.  Maybe you should debug your code properly, i.e. set a breakpoint and step through it line by line, and then you'll be able to see exactly what data is being used on each iteration.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I will try it right now.

Comment: Parsing CSVs is more complicated than it seems.  Rather than using `String.Split` use something like CSVHelper which will read and parse the file and store it in an IEnumerable(of T) for you with just a few lines of code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Once I needed to import a CSV file in my DataGridView and I did as in the code below (it is still in use by many users and it Works with no errors):

```
Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable 'you will not need this if your dgv has a datatable as datasource
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim fName As String = ""
    OpenFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "D:\TestFile"
    OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "CSV files(*.csv)|*.csv"
    OpenFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = True
    If (OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then
        fName = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
    End If

    Dim TextLine As String = ""
    Dim SplitLine() As String

    If System.IO.File.Exists(fName) = True Then
        Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(fName, Encoding.ASCII)
        Dim index As Integer = 0
        Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1
            If index > 0 Then
                TextLine = objReader.ReadLine()
                SplitLine = Split(TextLine, ",")
                dt.Rows.Add(SplitLine)
            Else
                TextLine = objReader.ReadLine()
            End If
            index = index + 1
        Loop
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
    Else
        MsgBox("File Does Not Exist")
    End If
End Sub
```

Hope it Works. ^^

Comment: Thank you, however I still get the same error Message, maybe its something with my CSV creating code, I will update the Question with it now.

Comment: Do you import fields that have inside their values ","? (for instance 3,14) Because if so, the reader will see them as field separators and will count more columns than you table has. Try using another separator in this case. Edit: I checked your image since I only saw it now. You are using "," inside your fields, that might be the source of your problem. Either use another separator or use "." instead of "," as decimal separator.

Comment: I changed the separator, it still gives me the same Error message. I rly have no Idea whats the problem here :/

Comment: I don't know what else could cause your error, the only things I did different from you were that I was not exporting the column headers and I used "." for decimal separator and "|" as field separator...

Comment: I could try do it without the headers

Answer (score 0):

When using a DataTable, you need to define the columns...otherwise, you get the error specified by the OP: " *The input array is longer than the number of columns in this table*" - the code above works if you add the following...

```
    dt.Columns.Add("Column1", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("Column2", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("Column3", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("Column4", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("Column5", GetType(String))

    etc.
```